# Is it possible to send messages on Facebook opened/closed group programmatically?

Tags: facebook, message

I have to periodically send messages on some both opened and closed Facebook page.
With my account I have the permissions to write to them (I already do it manually).

Can I setup an application written in any code, that sends messages (that are read from a file for example) to the given pages using the relative API?

If so please, give me an example of it.

Comment: Are you admin of the groups?

Comment: No I am not, I can only write whatever I want in those groups.

Comment: Then there is no API for you to post in the groups